# How to reformat data to reference what month a person is on during their contract using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset which portrays the contract start date and end date for a set of people as shown below:

```
> data = [['Andrew','2019-03','2019-06'],['Betty','2019-02','2019-07'],['Charlotte','2019-01','2019-08'],['Charlotte','2019-04','2019-06']]

> df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name','Contract Start Date','Contract End Date'])
```

I would like to reformat it so that it shows how long each person has been on their contract each month such as their first month would be signified as 1, second month 2 and so on. It should be noted that there is also the complication of if they renew their contract the counter should restart back to 1. Below is the expected output:

```
> data =[['Andrew',0,0,1,2,3,4,0,0],['Betty',0,1,2,3,4,5,6,0], 
        ['Charlotte',1,2,3,1,2,3,0,0]]

> df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name','2019-01','2019-02','2019-03','2019-04','2019-05','2019-06','2019-07','2019-08'])
```

Comment: You could do this: `df['time']= df['Contract End Date'].astype('datetime64') - df['Contract Start Date'].astype('datetime64')` and then with `df['time'].dt.days` you would get the numer of days difference. The number of months is not possible to get this way as all month have a different length, but you could divide by 30. If your dates are already `datetime64` just remove the `astype`.

Comment: ...or (because your dates don't include a day). Calculate the month number since year 0 like `df['Contract End Date'].astype('datetime64').dt.year*12 + df['Contract End Date'].astype('datetime64').dt.month - 1` (you should probably store the columns in `datetime64` for that), then just subtract the two numbers you get for start and end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Setup**

```
import pandas as pd
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

data = [
    ['Andrew','2019-03','2019-06'],
    ['Betty','2019-02','2019-07'],
    ['Charlotte','2019-01','2019-08'],
    ['Charlotte','2019-04','2019-06']
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name','Contract Start Date','Contract End Date'])

df['Contract Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Contract Start Date'])
df['Contract End Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Contract End Date'])
date_range = pd.date_range('2019-01', '2019-08', freq='MS')
```

**Create helper functions to find active contract**

Given a dataframe, return the most recent contract (by Start Date) based on a reference date. The use of `iloc` in the `return` statement is to ensure that it always returns a `pandas.Series` vs a `pandas.DataFrame`

```
def get_active_contract(df, _date):
    temp_df = df.sort_values('Contract Start Date')
    ret_df = temp_df[temp_df['Contract Start Date'] <= _date]

    return ret_df.iloc[-1] if len(ret_df) > 1 else temp_df.iloc[0]
```

**Create helper function to find tenure**

Given a dataframe, find the active contract (using the `active_contract` function up top). From here, if the date given is between the active contract, find the relative delta (in months) using the `relativedelta.relativedelta` function under the `dateutil` base package. The +1 is to adjust for the fact that counting tenure is not a zero indexed affair (i.e. if the start date is same as the current date, it should not be counted as 0 but rather 1). If the date given is outside the active contract, use 0.

```
def get_tenure(arg_df, current):
    srs = get_active_contract(arg_df, current)

    start = srs['Contract Start Date']
    end = srs['Contract End Date']
    name = srs['Name']
    if start <= current and current <= end:
        srs['tenure'] = relativedelta(current, start).months + 1

    else:
        srs['tenure'] = 0.0        

    return srs
```

**Create Table**

The steps are basically:

- Loop through the created `date_range`
- apply the `get_tenure` function and create a list of the dataframes showing the reference date and the tenure of each person at that date.
- create a master dataframe (`final_df`) by concatenating all of those said dataframes.
- pivot `final_df` to create the table.

The use of the `df.copy` is just for safety (not changing the original `df`).

```
for date in date_range:
    temp_df = df.copy()
    temp_df = temp_df.groupby(['Name']).apply(
        get_tenure, current=date
    )

    temp_df['date'] = date.strftime('%Y-%m')

    df_list.append(temp_df)

final_df = pd.concat(df_list)
final_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

pd.pivot_table(final_df, index=['Name'], columns=['date'], values=['tenure'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Idea is convert values to month periods for new columns.

First is necessary preprocessing `End` column for change values by next previous values per groups if condition:

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df.groupby('Name')['Contract Start Date'].shift(-1)).dt.to_period('m')
m = s > pd.to_datetime(df['Contract Start Date']).dt.to_period('m')
df['End'] = df['Contract End Date'].mask(m, s-1)
print (df)
        Name Contract Start Date Contract End Date      End
0     Andrew             2019-03           2019-06  2019-06
1      Betty             2019-02           2019-07  2019-07
2  Charlotte             2019-01           2019-08  2019-03
3  Charlotte             2019-04           2019-06  2019-06
```

And then use custom function per groups:

```
def f(x):
    zipped = zip(x['Contract Start Date'], x['End'])
    L = []
    for y1, y2 in zipped:
        per = pd.period_range(y1, y2, freq='m')
        rng = range(1, len(per)+1)
        out = pd.Series(rng, index=per)
        L.append(out)
    return pd.concat(L).to_frame().T

df1 = (df.groupby('Name')['Contract Start Date','End'].apply(f)
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
        .fillna(0)
        .astype(int)
        .reset_index()
       )
print (df1)
        Name  2019-01  2019-02  2019-03  2019-04  2019-05  2019-06  2019-07
0     Andrew        0        0        1        2        3        4        0
1      Betty        0        1        2        3        4        5        6
2  Charlotte        1        2        3        1        2        3        0
```